# Why can my metadata file not be found when trying to run my code?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

```
using NUnit.Framework;

using CounterCheck;

namespace Counter2.Test

{

    [TestFixture]

    class CounterTest

    {

        //Declare Counter object

        private Counter _counter;

        [SetUp]

        public void SetUp()

        {

            //Initialize the counter here..

            _counter = new Counter("test");

        }

        [Test]

        public void Initialize()

        {

            //Once setup is done, it should have count of zero

            int count = _counter.getCount();

            Assert.AreEqual(0, count);

        }

        [Test]

        public void IncrementCountByOne()

        {

            //Increment the counter by One

            _counter.Increment();

            int count = _counter.getCount();

            Assert.AreEqual(1, count);

        }

        [Test]

        public void IncrementCountMultipleTimes()

        {

            //Increment the counter by One

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            int count = _counter.getCount();

            Assert.AreEqual(6, count);

        }

        [Test]

        public void ResetCount()

        {

            //Increment the counter

            _counter.Increment();

            _counter.Increment();

            //And Reset the counter

            _counter.Reset();

            int count = _counter.getCount();

            Assert.AreEqual(0, count);

        }

    }

}
```

---

```
namespace CounterCheck

{

    public class Counter

    {

        private int _count;

        private string _name;

        public Counter(string name)

        {

            _name = name;

            _count = 0;

        }

        public void Increment()

        {

            _count++;

        }

        public void Reset()

        {

            _count = 0;

        }

        //Add getter method for count

        public int getCount()

        {

            return _count;

        }

    }

}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIZm2.png)

For some reason, a dll wasn't created for my class library project which I added onto my solution and referenced in another project. What is the reason for this and how do I fix it?

When going into my files, there is nothing there to begin with, why wasn't a the dll created and how can I rectify this?

Comment: Please do not insert screenshots for textual information. The "Metadata file 'whatever.dll' not found" simply means that the referenced assembly is not there, in which case all of the referencing projects (this time the unit test) produce this error. The posted code doesn't tell anything about the possible issue. Check the csproj file first. Is it a project reference or some assembly reference with some hardcoded HintPath?

Comment: I've checked the csproj file and cannot find anything which could cause the issue. It's an assembly reference.

Comment: If you can compile just the non-test project without any error, then the assembly must appear somewhere. But referencing it as an assembly reference is not really recommended. If you change any path, project name, debug/release, then you might not reference the expected assembly even if a file exists there with that name. Do you have a specific reason for not using a project reference instead?